# How do I set ylim for subplots using Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have more than thee columns for data frame.
I can set the bottom graph using ax=plt.gca(), but how do I set the limit for other subplots?

Below is the code I use for the plotting.

```
SomeDataFrame.plot(subplots=True, style=style, title='%s' % macID.upper(), grid=True, legend=True,)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.ylim=([lowlimit, highlimit])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SomeDataFrame.plot()` returns a list of the subplots it created. Using this return value you can access and manipulate them.

```
mysubplots = SomeDataFrame.plot(subplots=True, style=style, title='%s' % macID.upper(), grid=True, legend=True,)
firstplot = mysubplots[0]
firstplot.set_ylim=([lowlimit, highlimit])
secondplot = mysubplots[1]
secondplot.set_ylim=([lotherowlimit, otherhighlimit])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tested whether this works? Because I think you need to use `set_ylim()` instead of `ylim()`

Comment: Somewhere between my IPython shell and the comment field I lost the `set_` prefix. Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be:
  
`firstplot.set_ylim([lowlimit, highlimit]) `

instead of 

`firstplot.set_ylim=([lowlimit, highlimit])`

At least for me, only the former has the desired result, but not the latter.